# AMSerialPort: Use two ports in one project

Tags: objective-c, macos, serial-port

I'm writing a little application for `osx` to listen and send commands over a serial connection to an `Arduino` interface. That works great using `AMSerialPort`.

But now I need to forward some data to a second `Arduino`, so I need a second serial connection.

Is this possible with this framework? I've searched almost everywhere how to open a second port and get informed through the delegates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't really answer this question with regard to AMSerialPort. Though I've used AMSerialPort a lot in the past, it's been a while, and I've never tried to open two ports. However, I've just released my own Objective-C serial port library that definitely supports opening multiple ports simultaneously. It's called ORSSerialPort and you can get it here: https://github.com/armadsen/ORSSerialPort .

There's no trick to opening two serial ports with ORSSerialPort. Use the ORSSerialPortManager's `availablePorts` property to get all the available ports on the system.  In the `serialPort:didReceiveData:` delegate method, you can check which port received the data. Something like this:

```
NSArray *availablePorts = [[ORSSerialPortManager sharedSerialPortManager] availablePorts];

// The next two lines are simplified by assuming availablePorts has two ports 
// and you don't care which is which. Real code will be more sophisticated
self.port1 = [availablePorts objectAtIndex:0]; 
self.port2 = [availablePorts objectAtIndex:1];

self.port1.delegate = self;
self.port2.delegate = self;

[self.port1 open];
[self.port2 open];

- (void)serialPort:(ORSSerialPort *)port didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    if (port == self.port1) {
        // Data is from port1
    } else if (port == self.port2) {
        // Data is from port2
    }
}
```